# Difference between 모르다 and 몰라하다

Tags: verb

What's the difference between 모르다 and 몰라하다?
Some adjectives can form verbs by adding -어/여/아 하다, but in this case, 모르다 is verb.

Answer (score 2):

For [모르다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=29712&nation=eng), you can refer to a dictionary.

몰라 하다 is almost always used in the phrases 어쩔 줄 몰라 하다 and 어찌할 바를 몰라 하다. These phrases can be used to talk about others who are at a loss to know what to do (You *feel* that they are at a loss because of their actions or facial expressions). Normally, you should use 어쩔 줄 모르다 to talk about *yourself* because you *know* yourself.

Exceptions:

- You can also use 어쩔 줄 모르다 to talk about *others* when you use [this technique](https://literarydevices.net/omniscient/).
- You use 어쩔 줄 몰라 하다 to talk about *yourself* when you regard yourself as others.
- You use 어쩔 줄 몰라 하다 to *emphasize your actions and expressions* rather than the fact that you are at a loss to know what to do.

---

You may have thought that -어하다 should be used with an *adjective* to indicate that the subject has a *feeling* toward the object [(reference 1)](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=62888). The reality is that some verbs have qualities of adjectives and people attach -어하다 to *a few* (I mean, **psychological** ones) of such verbs. For example, 당황하다 is a psychological verb; you may have seen 당황해하다 as well [(reference 2)](https://m.cafe.daum.net/malcafe/7wQU/253?listURI=%2Fmalcafe%2F7wQU). 모르다 alone is *not* psychological, but the phrases I mentioned above is psychological. The standard dictionary does not deal with this case; the reason seems to be that they have not determined the spacing rule [(reference 3)](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=92818).